# can we improve dynamic array to make it more faster

Tags: algorithm, vector, arraylist, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

I have learned about dynamic array (non-fixed size array) as dynamic array as vector in C++ and Arraylist in Java
And how can we implement it.
Basically when the array is full we create another array of doubled size and copy the old items to the new array

So can we implement an array of non-fixed size with random access as a vector and Arraylist without spending time copying the old elements?
In other word, Is there data structure like that (dynamic size and random access and no need for copy elements)??

Comment: if you find it, talk to me, we'll make a lot of money.

Comment: so this my question until now nothing like that???  @TomElias

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "like", this is trivially impossible to already exists.

First the trivially impossible. When we create an array, we mark a section of memory as being only for that array.  If you have 3 such arrays that can grow without bound, one of them will eventually run into another.  Given that we can actually create arrays that are bigger than available memory (it just pages to disk), we have to manage this risk, not avoid it.

But how big an issue is it?  Copying data is `O(1)` per element, no matter how big it gets.  And the overhead is low.  The cost of this dynamicism is that you need to always check where the array starts.  But that's a pretty fast check.

Alternately we can move to paged memory.  Now an array access looks like, "Check what page it is on, then look at where it is in the page."  Now your array can grow, but you never change where anything is.  But if you want it to grow without bound, you have to add levels.  We can implement it, and it does avoid copying, but this form of indirection has generally NOT proven worth it for general purpose programming.  However paging is used in databases.  And it is also used by operating systems to manage turning what the program thinks is the address of the data, to the actual address in memory.  If you want to dive down that rabbit hole, [TLB is worth looking at](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer).

But there are other options that exist as well.  Instead of fixed sized pages, we can have variable sized ones.  This approach gets very complicated, very quickly.  But the result is very useful.  Look up [ropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) for more.

The browser that I wrote this on stores the text of what I wrote using a rope.  This is how it can easily offer features like multi-level undo and editing in the middle of the document.  However the raw performance of such schemes is significant.  It is clearly worthwhile if you need the features, but otherwise we don't do it.

In short, every set of choices we make has tradeoffs.  The one you'd like to optimize has what has proven to be the best tradeoff for offering dynamic size and raw performance.  That's why it appears everywhere from Python lists to C++ vectors.

Comment: "generally NOT proven worth it" - But if a TLB is implemented in hardware, how is it not worth it in the general case?  Too many TLB misses after the DA grows too large?

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug I said, "...for general purpose programming." Obviously the TLB is worth doing well. That's why it is built into hardware. But that's a special case. And general purpose programming typically doesn't deal with such low level details.